# Custom password reset view class returning ImproperlyConfigured exception

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am attempting on implementing the `password_reset` in `django.contrib.auth.views` as described shown https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L133

But i have absolute no luck with this as i keep getting following exception:

```
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value: The included urlconf tutorial.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
```

My urls.py for the project (tutorial):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^adminp/', include('adminApp.urls')),
    url(r'^mobile/', include('mobileApp.urls')),
)
```

My urls.py for the app:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....
    url(r'^login/$', UserLoginView.as_view(), name='admin_user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', UserLogoutView.as_view(), name='admin_user_logout'),
    url(r'^password/reset/$', UserPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='admin_password_reset'),
    url(r'^password/reset/done/$', UserPasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='admin_password_reset_done'),
    ....
```

And my class:

```
class UserPasswordResetView(FormView):
    template_name = 'adminApp/registration/password_reset_form.html'
    form_class = MyPasswordResetForm
    email_template_name = 'adminApp/registration/password_reset_email.html'
    subject_template_name = 'changeMe'
    post_reset_redirect = reverse('adminApp:admin_password_reset_done')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        password_reset(self.request)
        return super(UserPasswordResetView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  318.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  346.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  341.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/Users/Jimbo/Dropbox/Sandbox/tutorial/tutorial/urls.py" in <module>
  12.     url(r'^adminp/', include('adminApp.urls')),
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  26.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/Users/Jimbo/Dropbox/Sandbox/tutorial/adminApp/urls.py" in <module>
  3. from adminApp import views
File "/Users/Jimbo/Dropbox/Sandbox/tutorial/adminApp/views.py" in <module>
  44. class UserPasswordResetView(FormView):
File "/Users/Jimbo/Dropbox/Sandbox/tutorial/adminApp/views.py" in UserPasswordResetView
  49.     post_reset_redirect = reverse('admin_password_reset_done')
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  509.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  387.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  296.             self._populate()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  262.         for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  350.             raise ImproperlyConfigured("The included urlconf %s doesn't have any patterns in it" % self.urlconf_name)
```

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /adminp/password/reset/
Exception Value: The included urlconf tutorial.urls doesn't have any patterns in it
Now if i comment out the `post_reset_redirect` it works fine, so i assume that its not really finding the `admin_password_reset_done` name? And why is that?

**UPDATE:**

I replaced `reverse` with `reverse_lazy` as according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7430924/531203, but it invoked another error which may or not be in the same domain:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: Reverse for 'password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

When `reverse_lazy` is used it assumes that `post_reset_redirect` variable is none and sets: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L144

Comment: The pasted `urls.py` is `tutorial.urls`?

Comment: @user995394, its the urls.py of what i call app1, which has the class.

Comment: I think the problem lies somewhere else in your urls configuration. Where is the `tutorial.urls` mentioned in the exception message? You're seeing the problem at that line because of `reverse()`, which goes through all your urls and can often uncover problems. It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with `admin_password_reset_done`.

Comment: Kevin, please check my latest update. I cannot determine any errors in my urls.py file, at all. Basically i have commented out everything just to be sure and it does not solve the issue. When i use `reverse_lazy` it infacts override the `post_reset_redirect` variable with its default value: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original problem was with circular imports. `reverse_lazy` fixed that.

You don't seem to be using the `password_reset` function correctly. The function you linked to is expecting to be passed keyword arguments, it's not going to see the variables defined in your class. Also, you're ignoring the return value - you should be returning it instead.

I'm not familiar with this part of the auth system, but these appear to be regular function-based views, so I would just write my own and pass the appropriate parameters to `password_reset`.

```
def my_password_reset_view(request):
    return password_reset(request,
        template_name='adminApp/registration/password_reset_form.html',
        email_template_name='adminApp/registration/password_reset_email.html',
        subject_template_name='changeMe',
        post_reset_redirect=reverse('adminApp:admin_password_reset_done'),
        password_reset_form=MyPasswordResetForm)
```

And similarly with the other views.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to invoke the function?

Comment: Is it possible with Class based views aswell?

Comment: Sure, but you won't really be using any of the features of CBVs. You can just inherit from `View` and call `password_reset` as above from both `get()` and `post()`. Or you could override `dispatch()`.

Comment: I realised it was a huge hassle, so i went with the function method instead. Thanks.